# ¿Es posible definir los atributos de una clase del mismo tipo mediante un vector?

Tags: c++, array, diseño-de-clases, atributos

Estoy ahora mismo aprendiendo a trabajar con clases en C++ y haciendo diferentes programas pequeñitos para coger soltura con las clases y objetos.
Ahora mismo estoy con un sencillo programa que permita gestionar usuarios; crear nuevos, editarlos, borrarlos etc.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct User{
private:
    //Attributes
    std::string name;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string nick;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

public:
    User();
    ~User();
};
```

Esto digamos que seria la forma convencional de trabajar los atributos. A día de hoy sabría trabajar sin problema con cada uno de los atributos por separado y crear los métodos para modificarlos, crearlos o borrarlos.

Pero me he dado cuenta que al definir la clase User muchos de los atributos son del mismo tipo y pertenecen al mismo "concepto". Dejo un código de ejemplo.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct User{
private:
    //Attributes
    std::vector<std::string>name{}; //Vector at(0)=firstName; at(1)=lastName; at(2)=nick;
    std::vector<int>birth{}; // at(0)=Day; at(1)=Month; at(2)=year

public:
    User();
    ~User();
};
```

Al ser por ejemplo el nombre apellidos y nick miembros de un mismo conjunto ¿podría trabajar con ellos con un vector? ¿Es una buena practica?
Por ejemplo al crear métodos seria más escueto. Pues con un mismo método puedo trabajar con todos los parámetros de un vector.
Aún no me he puesto a programar los métodos porque antes quería saber si es una forma viable, y sobretodo si es una forma correcta.

Gracias a todos! Un saludo

Comment: ¿ Cúal es la pregunta ? ¿ Que problema te has encontrado ?

Comment: La pregunta es si es una buena practica trabajar de este modo los atributos. 
En todos los manuales y guías que he consultado trabajan los atributos del primer modo.
Y se que al final hay muchas maneras de programar una misma idea, pero no todas son buenas practicas. 
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Aún no me he puesto a programar los métodos porque antes quería saber si es una forma viable, y sobretodo si es una forma correcta.

Pues depende de lo que entiendas por *correcta*:

- Entendiendo por *correcta* la sintaxis del programa pues sí, podría ser correcta.
- Atendiendo al mantenimiento y legiblidad del código, **NO es correcto**

Razones hay varias, pero creo que para muestra un botón. Imagínate el siguiente código, el cual podría salir con tu nueva versión:

```
std::vector<User> users;

for( int i=0; i<users.size(); i++ )
{
  users[i].name[0] = getName();

  if( users[i].name[0].size() < 5 )
  {
    std::cout << users[i].name[0] << " has a wrong size\n";
    return;
  }
  users[i].name[1] = getSurname();

  if( users[i].name[1].size() < 8 )
  {
    std::cout << users[1].name[1] << " has a wrong size\n";
    return;
  }

  users[i].name[2] = getNickname();

  if( users[i].name[2].size() < 5 )
  {
    std::cout << users[2].name[i] << " has a wrong size\n";
    return;
  }

  users[i].name[2] = anotherOne();

  doSomethingWith(users[i].name[2]);

  users[i].name[3] = andAnotherOne();

  pleaseValidateIt(users[i].name[3]);

  // ...
  users[i].name[10] = andTheLastOne();
}
```

¿Te parece un código legible? ¿Ves algún error? Haberlos los hay, te lo garantizo.

La lógica que pretendes no te proporciona ninguna ventaja:

- La clase `vector` usa memoria dinámica (acceso más lento).
- Accedes a las variables por índice (facil equivocarse).
- Ante cambios en la clase (eliminas, por ejemplo, un elemento de `name`) es complicado editar el código para que se acceda siempre al elemento esperado.
- Las variables no tienen nombre (menos legible).

De hecho, para hacer lo que propones no tienes que crear clases nuevas... usa tuplas:

```
using User = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, int, int int>;

User user;
std::get<0>(user) = "name";
std::get<1>(user) = "lastName";
std::get<2>(user) = "nick";
std::get<3>(user) = date.day;
std::get<4>(user) = date.month;
std::get<5>(user) = date.year;
```

¿De verdad te parece que este uso es apropiado? A mi desde luego no me lo parece.

Piensa que una cosa es que un objeto almacene una **colección de elementos**, los cuales están íntimamente relacionados entre sí (una colección de botones, resultados de un equipo, fecha de eventos importantes), y otra muy distinta es tener atributos del mismo tipo pero con significados diferentes (no es lo mismo un día que un año, por mucho que ambos sean números).

Así que para almacenar colecciones de elementos, sí, usa `std::vector`, `std::array` o el contenedor que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades, pero para el resto de casos crea variables independientes. Tu salud te lo agradecerá a corto, medio y largo plazo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. En efecto el código queda extremadamente confuso.
Iré ahora mismo a investigar sobre Tuple.
Gracias de nuevo!